# Authentication interfers with enricher in Mule 3.3

Tags: mule, esb

I'm currently writing a rather simple mule-flow that uses basic authentication

```
<custom-transformer class="com.org.HttpRequestToMyRequest" name="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
<flow name="Input_Flow" doc:name="Input_Flow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="http://12.23.34.45" port="1234" path="/foo">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting flow"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting_Flow">
    <transformer ref="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Transform Http Request to POJO with interesting methods"/>
    <enricher target="#[variable:authorized]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.45.56" port="1234" path="foo/bar" method="GET" disableTransportTransformer="true" 
        responseTransformer-refs="ObjectToString" doc:name="Authorization Service"/>
    </enricher>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:authorized=true">
            <processor-chain>
                <component class="com.org.MyClass"/>
                <transformer ref="MyObjToString"/>
                <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when SOMETHING ELSE>
            DO SOMETHING ELSE
        </when>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

If I remove the http-security-filter then this flow works as expected and the payload in the MuleMessage is of the type MyRequest returned by the HttpRequestToMyRequest transformer. But once i add the security-filter the enricher changes my payload from the expected type to a byte[]. If i convert the byte[] to a String then it turns out to be the instancename of MyRequest (com.org.MyRequest@15ae9009).

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Just to be clear. Here are three flow xml fragments where two behave well and the last one has the strange behaviour i don't understand.

This flow, where I've commented out the security-filter on the inbound endpoint, works as expected and the ClassNameLogger statements prints out, in order, String, MyRequest, MyRequest.

```
<custom-transformer class="com.org.HttpRequestToMyRequest" name="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
<custom-transformer class="com.org.ClassNameLogger" name="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Java"/>
<flow name="Input_Flow" doc:name="Input_Flow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="http://12.23.34.45" port="1234" path="/foo">
            <!-- <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/> -->
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting flow"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting_Flow">
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <transformer ref="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Transform Http Request to POJO with interesting methods"/>
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <enricher target="#[variable:authorized]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.45.56" port="1234" path="foo/bar" method="GET" disableTransportTransformer="true" 
        responseTransformer-refs="ObjectToString" doc:name="Authorization Service"/>
    </enricher>
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:authorized=true">
            <processor-chain>
                <component class="com.org.MyClass"/>
                <transformer ref="MyObjToString"/>
                <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when SOMETHING ELSE>
            DO SOMETHING ELSE
        </when>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

This flow, where I've commented out the enricher, works as expected, aside from the fact that it doesn't enter the choise since the variable set by the enricher is not defined. The ClassNameLogger statements prints out, in order, String, MyRequest, MyRequest.

```
<custom-transformer class="com.org.HttpRequestToMyRequest" name="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
<custom-transformer class="com.org.ClassNameLogger" name="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Java"/>
<flow name="Input_Flow" doc:name="Input_Flow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="http://12.23.34.45" port="1234" path="/foo">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting flow"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting_Flow">
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <transformer ref="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Transform Http Request to POJO with interesting methods"/>
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <!-- <enricher target="#[variable:authorized]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.45.56" port="1234" path="foo/bar" method="GET" disableTransportTransformer="true" 
        responseTransformer-refs="ObjectToString" doc:name="Authorization Service"/>
    </enricher> -->
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:authorized=true">
            <processor-chain>
                <component class="com.org.MyClass"/>
                <transformer ref="MyObjToString"/>
                <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when SOMETHING ELSE>
            DO SOMETHING ELSE
        </when>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

This flow, where I have both the enricher and the security-filter in place, doesn't work as expected and the ClassNameLogger statements prints out, in order, String, MyRequest, byte[].

```
<custom-transformer class="com.org.HttpRequestToMyRequest" name="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Java"/>
<custom-transformer class="com.org.ClassNameLogger" name="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Java"/>
<flow name="Input_Flow" doc:name="Input_Flow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="http://12.23.34.45" port="1234" path="/foo">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <flow-ref name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting flow"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="Sorting_Flow" doc:name="Sorting_Flow">
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <transformer ref="HttpRequestToMyRequest" doc:name="Transform Http Request to POJO with interesting methods"/>
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <enricher target="#[variable:authorized]">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="12.34.45.56" port="1234" path="foo/bar" method="GET" disableTransportTransformer="true" 
        responseTransformer-refs="ObjectToString" doc:name="Authorization Service"/>
    </enricher>
    <transformer ref="ClassNameLogger" doc:name="Logs The Class Name of MuleMessage payload"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="header:INVOCATION:authorized=true">
            <processor-chain>
                <component class="com.org.MyClass"/>
                <transformer ref="MyObjToString"/>
                <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when SOMETHING ELSE>
            DO SOMETHING ELSE
        </when>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>
```

**Edit 2**

The code in the HttpRequestToMyRequest transformer

```
public class HttpRequestToMyRequest extends AbstractMessageTransformer{
    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {    
    if("/foo".equals(message.getInboundProperty("http.request.path")){
        return new MyFooRequest();
    }
    if("/bar".equals(message.getInboundParameter("http.request.path")){
        return new MyBarRequest();      
    }   
    else return new MyEmptyRequest();
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

Apparently this was something Mule 3.3 specific. Once I upgraded to 3.4 everything started working as expected.

Comment: I see you use the old style expression syntax: what Mule version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mule 3.3.0 but thats just because I havn't got around to update to 3.4. If I'm using old syntax or weird constructs that's because I'm rather new to Mule so any pointers are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mule 3.4, I notice no difference of payload type with or without the `http-security-filter` element.

It is either a `java.lang.String` if the request is an HTTP GET or `java.io.InputStream` if it is a POST or PUT.

Since you are on 3.3, you are possibly hitting a bug that is gone in 3.4, since I don't have any issue. If that is the case, finding a workaround for the issue on 3.3 would be hairy: upgrading to 3.4 is the path forward.

Comment: Maybee i was unclear... I only used GET request so far so the payload is always String up until the HttpRequestToMyRequest transformer. After the transformer the payload is a POJO of type MyRequest. Then after the enricher but before the choise the payload all of a sudden is the string com.org.MyRequest@15ae9009 as a byte[]. Although if I comment out the security filter the payload after the enricher is still a POJO with type MyRequest and everything works.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. Can I assume that `HttpRequestToMyRequest` only registers `java.lang.String` as its source type and `com.org.MyRequest` as its return data type? Also can you share how is `HttpRequestToMyRequest` configured in XML? Also please specify the base class of this transformer. Finally why using such an old version of Mule? If you ought to be on 3.3 at least use 3.3.1 not 3.3.0 to get some important bug fixes.

Comment: Yes HttpRequestToMyRequest only registered String as source and MyRequest as return type and extended AbstractTransformer. Since then I changed it to AbstractMessageTransformer just to se if it made a difference but it didn't. As to how the transformer is configured in XML, I added a extra line at the top of my original post.

Comment: Although I dont think the HttpRequestToMyRequest transformer has anything to do with the problem se my edit above for more clarification.

Comment: Any detail counts in Mule as there are many possible interactions and side-effects. Could you share the code of HttpRequestToMyRequest?

Comment: Sure I edited my original post with the code in HttpRequestToMyRequest but I really don't think the transformer has anything to do with it since everything works if I comment out the http-securty-filter.

Comment: You never know, there are possible side-effects. But I can't reproduce the issue, granted, I'm on 3.4.0. Could you give a quick try to 3.4.0 too?

Comment: That actually worked. I just upgraded to 3.4 and the problem just disappeared. This makes me rather sceptical to the way mule works. How is it even remotely possible to predict the behaviour of a mule flow with "action at a distance" like this? Anyway thank you very much for your help. If you just restate your last comment as a answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can accept it. As Mule progresses and bugs are killed, there should be less and less of these strange side-effects. Be sure to have a complete set of functional tests for your projects as a safety net.