# Mule security filter breaking flow

Tags: security, serialization, collections, mule, split

I'm completely at a loss with my knowledge gap.

Mule 3.3.1 CE.  I must use that version for now.

I have a flow which works fine until I try to use a security filter with valid credentials.

The Mule code follows.  It won't make much business sense as I've pared it down to the minimum that produces the problem.  Normally the outbound call is in a separate flow, but I pulled it into the Main flow for the example.

If I have the security filter on the inbound endpoint commented out and execute this, I get the expected response of the logger message and the "foo" return payload.

```
<https:connector name="HTTPSConnector"  validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <https:tls-key-store path="/opt/eai/common/keystore/EAIKeystore.jks" keyPassword="${key.password}" storePassword="${store.password}"/>
</https:connector>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="PortalUser" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authManager"/>
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<flow name="Main" doc:name="Main">
    <https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="10029" path="sites/r.v1" mimeType="text/xml" encoding="UTF-8" connector-ref="HTTPSConnector">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    </https:inbound-endpoint>

    <custom-transformer class="com.ca.eai.esb.transformer.site.StrategySplittingTransformer" doc:name="Split"/>
    <collection-splitter/>

    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
            address="${https.outbound.account.sap-nameaddress}" 
            connector-ref="HTTPSConnector"
            mimeType="text/xml" responseTimeout="${https.outbound.timeout}"/>

    <logger level="INFO" message="GOT HERE"/>

    <set-payload value="foo"/>
</flow>
```

The custom transformer is also pared down to the minimum:

```
@Override
public Object transformMessage( MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding )
{
    MuleMessageCollection collection = new DefaultMessageCollection( message.getMuleContext() );

    collection.addMessage( message );

    return collection;
}
```

If I uncomment the security filter and pass in bad credentials, I get the expected security exception.

If, however, I pass in valid credentials, I get an exception that it can't serialize.

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:857)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Can someone tell me why adding a security filter causes this?

Comment: Note: the original exception was also a NotSerializableException, but it listed the class of the object I transformed the input into using XSL.  I removed all that as seeming not germane to the problem that adding security produces an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in 3.4.x.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17930063/387927 and the comments below it.